# How to copy an integer from vector<char>

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am working now on wav files, I am tring parse them. I don't wanna use libraries for now .
I open the wav file with fstream and read all the data to vector.
Now I want to parse wav file header . For example I want to get filesize which is between 4th and 8th bytes. I want to assign this to a integer . I would accomplish this with memcpy easily .But since it is C++ I don't wanna use memcpy. 
The solution I end up with :

```
std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator vectorIte = soundFileDataVec.begin();
vawParams.totalfilesize = 0;
//Since it is little endian I used reverse_copy
std::reverse_copy(vectorIte + 4, vectorIte + 7, (unsigned char*)&vawParams.totalfilesize);
```

I am not happy with (unsigned char*) cast to integer pointer .I suspect there is a better way than I do. Can you please advice me a better way?

Comment: Is it possible to read the .wav header into a struct instead? (Possibly with usage of alignment pragmas?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vectors use contiguous storage locations for their elements, their elements can be accessed using offsets on regular pointers to its elements. So if you don't want a `memcpy` then a trivial solution is:

```
int header = *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(&soundFileDataVec[4]);
```

This reads you four bytes (that you may need to convert from one endianness to another).

Comment: I think your form is more understandable. I were expecting for a std function for this case because I don't like this casts. I think such function doesn't exists. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Once you are in the realm of binary serialization, if you want to be portable and you don't want to use a library you pretty much have to get beneath the abstraction layers of how a type is presented to you in a programming language. You have to understand exactly how it's stored in the file, and you have to understand exactly how to get it back out and translate it into the representation of types that you have on your compiler on the platform you're compiling for.

Trying to avoid casts is probably inherently wrong-headed under those constraints.